# Excel: add up varying columns

Tags: excel

In Excel I would like to add up fields automatically, but the column numbers that needs to be added up change from row to row.

I have prepared an example of what I mean:
I have 3 companies:

1. Unicredit
2. HVB
3. Wechselbank

Over time HVB took over Wechselbank (in 1998), shown by the change from 3 to 2 in the first table, and later (in 2005) Unicredit took over HVB (2 becomes 1 for HVB *and* Wechselbank). So now only one company is left. But all the 3 previous companies still exist and have their own separate assets.

I have build an ownership table in which is kept track of who is the parent company at any point in time. And I have a table of all the assets per entity. How can I add them up automatically per parent company (as done manually in the final table?)

[image]

In words I need a formula that:

- for each year and id in the final table (e.g. HVB (2), 1999)
- looks up all the entities that are owned (retrieves id {2, 3})
- adds up all the assets for the entities from the asset table (adds up the 1999 values of id {2,3} -> 52+14 =66)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it myself.

It turned out that a simple sumproduct formula does the trick!

e.g. in C18

```
=sumproduct(($B6:$D6=C$15)*($G6:$I6))
```

And it also works if the 'if' data is in another sheet as is the sumdata. Which was exactly what I needed!